# MySQL doesn't yet support Limit&& in/all?

Tags: mysql, subquery, limit

my query is as follow:

```
 SELECT * FROM `C_Institute`
 WHERE `ID` IN
 (SELECT `instituteID` FROM `C_Faculty` WHERE `ID` 
 IN (SELECT `facultyID` FROM `C_EducationalGroup` WHERE `ID` 
 IN (SELECT `educationalGroupID` FROM `C_StudyField` WHERE `ID` 
 IN (SELECT `studyFieldID` FROM `b_PersonEmployment` WHERE `personID`=1 ORDER BY `startDate` limit 1) )));
```

but mysql not support `limit` and `in` on subquery. I don't know how I can write this query.
can anyone help me please?

thanks in advance

Comment: which version od mysql you are using?

Comment: yuo have error  ?  show th error message .. wrong result updated your question add  a proper data sample and the expetced  result

Comment: @scaisEdge MySQL 5.7.21

Answer (score 2):

You may rewrite this query a series of joins:

```
SELECT c1.*
FROM C_Institute c1
INNER JOIN C_Faculty c2
    ON c1.ID = c2.instituteID
INNER JOIN C_EducationalGroup c3
    ON c2.ID = c3.facultyID
INNER JOIN C_StudyField c4
    ON c3.ID = c4.educationalGroupID
INNER JOIN b_PersonEmployment b
    ON c4.ID = b.studyFieldID
WHERE b.personID = 1
ORDER BY b.startDate
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming ID in each table is referring to the other table then,

Try this and let me know :

```
select * from C_Institute c join C_Faculty f on c.ID=F.instituteID left join C_EducationalGroup e on f.ID=e.facultyID left join C_StudyField sf on e.ID=sf.educationalGroupID left join b_PersonEmployment p on sf.ID=p.studyFieldID where p.personID=1 order by p.startDate limit 1;
```

Also, share your tables description for more clues

Comment: I think it's not good idea. the tables is too big and join has cost a lot.

Comment: If you have indexing on those columns then I think it should go fine. Further you can analyse the query with "EXPLAIN plan "  to have more detailed look.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all your answer. but I think join is not good way to solve this problem. I've done it by two query(maybe not good idea but better than join):

```
SET @studyFieldID =(SELECT `studyFieldID` FROM `b_PersonEmployment` WHERE `personID`=1 ORDER BY `startDate` limit 1); 
SELECT * FROM `C_Institute`
 WHERE `ID` IN
 (SELECT `instituteID` FROM `C_Faculty` WHERE `ID` 
 IN (SELECT `facultyID` FROM `C_EducationalGroup` WHERE `ID` 
 IN (SELECT `educationalGroupID` FROM `C_StudyField` WHERE `ID`=@studyFieldID 
  )));
```